# Facebook logout remove profile picture, and name

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am having problems with remove, and reset the text from Facebook on logout. The picture and name is still there.

```
        /// Logged OUT \\\ ---- The problem
    if (profile == null) {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
        name.setText("Anonymous user");
        System.out.print("Profile == null!");
    }
```

Am using this code to handle the process setting profile picture to blank, and set the name to "Anonymous user". This dosn't work for me. Could someone provide help?

Below you can see part of my code.

```
public class Profile extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

WebView web;
ArrayList<NavigationDrawerItem> listItems;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
ListView list;

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private TextView name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");
    com.facebook.Profile profile = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    final ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    final TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);


    /// Logged IN \\\
        if (profile != null) {
            profilePictureView.getProfileId();
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
            name.setText(profile.getName());
        }

    /// Logged OUT \\\ ---- The problem
    if (profile == null) {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
        name.setText("Anonymous user");
        System.out.print("Profile == null!");
    }


    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("details", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //After referencing your Views, add this.
    String nameStr = sharedPrefs.getString("name", null);
    String idStr = sharedPrefs.getString("id", null);
    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (token != null) {
        if (nameStr != null) name.setText(nameStr);
        if (idStr != null) profilePictureView.setProfileId(idStr);
    }
    //.. Do the same for other profile data


        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                com.facebook.Profile profile = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                profilePictureView.getProfileId();
                profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
                name.setText(profile.getName());

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("name", profile.getName());
                editor.putString("id", profile.getId());
                //.. Do the same for other profile data
                editor.commit();

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.i("Error", "Error");
            }

        });
```

<-- The rest of the code -->

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you have to override the `onCurrentAccessTokenChanged` method.

Example:

```
AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() 
{
     @Override
     protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
          if (newToken == null){
             info.setText(" ");
             profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
          }
      }
};
```

The above code should go into `onCreate` method.